# Rails ActiveRecord: Uniqueness validation on a nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have tried the solutions found in the search results but validation is still not working.
Here's the model setup:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :trans_items, class_name: "TransItem", dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :transact
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :trans_items

class TransItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :transact, class_name: "Transaction", foreign_key: :transaction_id, inverse_of: :trans_items
    validates_uniqueness_of :material_id, :scope => :transaction_id
end
```

This still becomes created successfully:

```
Transaction
> trans_items
 - material_id: 9
 - transaction_id: 1
> trans_items
 - material_id: 9
 - transaction_id: 1
```

**UPDATE 1:**

As suggested below, I also tried this solution but still not working:

`validates :material_id, uniqueness: { scope: :transaction_id }`

If it would help, the create form is this (using nested_form gem):

```
<%= f.link_to_add "Add Material", :trans_items, :data => { :target => "#trans_items" }  %>
  <table id="trans_items" class="table table-condensed" cellspacing="0">
   <%= f.fields_for :trans_items, wrapper: false do |builder| %>
      <tr class="fields">
        <td width="10%">
          <%= builder.label :qty %><br>
          <%= builder.number_field :qty, :class => 'form-control input-sm', :step => 'any' %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= builder.label :material_id %>
          <%= builder.collection_select(:material_id, Material.all, :id, :material_display_dropdown, {prompt: "Select one..."}, { :class => "form-control input-sm" })  %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= f.link_to_remove "Remove" %>
        </td>
      </tr> 
    <% end %>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
validates :material_id, uniqueness: { scope: :transaction_id }
```

Comment: Try to use index [Back it up with a unique index](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of#269-Back-it-up-with-a-unique-index)

Comment: Thanks. It worked, however, I get this error `SQLite3::ConstraintException not unique`.

Comment: SQLite is just a rails default, use mysql instead.

Comment: After submitting the form, I get the Rails error page: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique in TransactionsController#create` `SQLite3::ConstraintException: columns material_id, transaction_id are not unique: INSERT INTO "trans_items" ("created_at", "material_id", "qty", "transaction_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`